# Program a Dos File to execute a command line Run

Tags: command-line, dos

The Command Line entry is: eraserl.exe -recycled
It is needed to run "Eraser" ( http://eraser.heidi.ie/ ) in order to overwrite the Recycle Bin when no Recycle Bin Icon is available.

How do I run this command from a DOS file (.bat, .cmd or .whatever)?

(BTW, installing a lost Recyckle Bin is no easy trick!)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question, but to run a command in a bat file all you need to do is put the line or lines you need to execute in a text file and save it with a .bat extension.

For example

```
Eraserl.exe -recycled
```

This assumes the eraserl.exe file is in your path.  If not you'll need to include the entire path to the executable

```
C:\pathtoexe\eraserl.exe -recycled
```

Answer (score 0):

C:\pathtoexe\eraserl.exe -recycled